# Windows 10 dual boot with Mint: Not able to boot into Windows anymore

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

Here's how I configured my drive after installing Win10:
[image]

So I made one partition for Windows at 73Gb and in the remaining space I created a 30Gb partition for the "/" root folder for Mint and a 16Gb partition for the "swap" space. And I got an error when trying to install saying something like "No EFI System partition was found...etc" so I created a small 632Mb EFI partition and it worked.

However I'm not greeted with any menu after bios has loaded where I get to choose which OS to boot into. That's what I expected, but I assume I need to do some more manual configuring for this since I choose to make my own partitions and all that.
So what have I missed? Is this looking ok overall, the way I've organized the partitions?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**
grub file:
[image]

Comment: It looks like Windows was installed in legacy mode, you can tell by the MBR (master boot  record) partitioning.  That could become a problem for booting Windows, but I think you'd still see a Windows entry in the GRUB boot menu.  /// Can you show the contents of `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: Okey, I was unaware that it could be a problem or that I was in fact installing it in legacy mode at all. I've included a picture of my grub file. If it will be necessary to reinstall windows, how would I go about to install it in "NOT legacy mode"? Thanks for helping.

Comment: I would not recommend reinstalling Windows at this point.  Can you see in gnome disk utility which of the partitions is bootable if any?

Comment: You can enable the GRUB boot menu by removing pr commenting out the GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE line and changing GRUB_TIMEOUT to 10 or whatever amount of seconds you prefer.   After that, you'll need to run `sudo update-grub` from a terminal.  Watch the output to see if it finds your Windows installation.